# ranges::views:transform failing on clang

Tags: c++, std-ranges

The following simple program compiles with g++ (12.1.0) and fails with clang (14.0.6) with a very long and not so descriptive error

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
  auto fview = std::ranges::views::transform(v, [](auto p) { return p; });
  return 0;
}
```

The error with clang is `error: no matching function for call to '__begin'` and it goes on for about 183 lines to paste here. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You need to specify `-stdlib=libc++` to use `libc++` instead of `libstdc++`.

Comment: that's unfortunately not possible since `libc++` misses even more c++20 headers like `<compare>`.

Comment: libc++ definitely implements `<compare>`.